# scala return case mismatch for case class

Tags: function, scala, return, case-class, mismatch

I am suppose to return a case class called Entry, so I can't change the function's signature. When I filled my case class and try to return it, I get the following error:

```
<console>:13: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Entry(in method apply)
 required: <empty>.Entry
```

I am not sure why the function is asking for that type

```
def apply(line: String) : Entry = {
   case class Entry(account:String, password:String, UID:Int, GID:Int,
                    GECOS:String, directory:String, shell:String)
   val fields = line.split(":")
   val x = Entry(fields(0), fields(1), fields(2).toInt, fields(3).toInt,
         fields(4), fields(5), fields(6))
    x
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a guess but I believe `Entry` is defined elsewhere. I say this because you have a reference to the "Entry" class in the function signature but you're also defining a case class within the function body. The `Entry` that you are returning is not the `Entry` that the function expects.

Comment: Thanks, it is the problem.